# unable to extract text from BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to fetch data from one of the html page using beautifulsoup and regex but unable to do so.

html_data:

```
<td class="col-a size a-update">200 MB<span class="next-size">1250</span></td>
```

I want to extract only 200 MB but not 1250

I tried below code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_string = '<td class="coll-4 size mob-uploader">194.5 MB<span 
class="seeds">3422</span></td>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_string, 'html.parser')
size =  soup.find('td', {'class': 'size'}).getText()
print size
```

but I got both 194.5 MB3422

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved by using below code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_string = '<td class="coll-4 size mob-uploader">194.5 MB<span 
class="seeds">3422</span></td>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_string, 'html.parser')
size =  soup.find('td', {'class': 'size'}).contents[0]
print size
```